# Row Count within Make Table Query | MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Essentially I have a Make Table Query comprised of a few different tables that is created with no issues.

I would like this table being created to also have a virtual column called ID and to increment each row comprised in the query.

Is something like possible to include in the Make Table Query as an expression?

Comment: Tables do not have 'virtual' columns. It's either there or it isn't. Can have an autonumber type field.

Comment: Not quite what I meant. Can an expression be added to a MS Access Query that adds an auto number column field based on how many rows come out of the query result

Comment: Might look at my revised answer in your other question. Yes, a sequence number can be calculated in query and that value saved to records in another table by either INSERT or MAKE TABLE action.

Answer (score 0):

My *RowNumber* function is for exactly this:

```vb
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID with an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID without an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID]), CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowNumber(vbNullString, True)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' 2020-05-29. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5
  
    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection

    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber
    
    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)
        
        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If

        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If
    
    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count
  
Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function
    
Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

Please study the in-line comments for typical usage.

Full documentation and demo can be found in my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, this is an issue that come up often in Access. The best solution that I've found is to define a new table with the resultant fields and an auto-increment Id and then convert the mktbl query into an update query which populates that table.